# Duplication with rotation only on the Z axis

Tags: modifiers

I'd like to know if it's possible to duplicate an object along a curve so that it follows the curve but only rotate on one axis (Z axis), and not on the X or Y axes. First picture is the result I want, second picture is the result I get with an Array + Curve Modifier. Dupliframes doesn't give any good result either. Thanks in advance!

[image: picture here]

file is here: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48706

EDIT : solution found with a Dupliframes, then a Constraint > Limit Rotation for my object... Thanks everyone

Comment: Add your blend file to the question via http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. That way people don't have to guess at how you've set up things, and can give you an answer that you can actually use.

Comment: Thanks dr Sybren. Ok I've found a solution, I use Dupliframes, then I use a Constraint > Limit Rotation for my object, and I click on Limit X and Limit Y. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please write this as an answer, ideally with a screenshot of the setup, so that others can easily find your solution as well. It's the least you can do for the community after asking for help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Until 2.79:** I use *Dupliframes*, then I use a *Constraint > Limit Rotation* for my object, and I click on *Limit X* and *Limit Y*.

**Since 2.8:** See Gorgious solution [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/cant-get-my-instanced-objects-dupliverts-to-work/165691?noredirect=1#comment352464_165691).

Comment: can you add more detail to this question/answer? Now the question has a broken link, it would be helpful to have more information so that other users can learn.

Comment: sure, that's what I was planning to do, now the method has changed, plus there are the geometry nodes, I'll do it soon