# How to control the orientation of an Arrayed Mesh Object following a Curve (NurbsPath)

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make the stairs railing poles with an Array following a Curve.
Is there a way to control which way the Poles are facing?
I want to point them all straight down (vertically).

[image: Stairs Railing Pole]

Comment: maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve/165691#165691

Comment: Hi! Unless we're all missing something, it's surprisingly awkward. Check out @Gorgious' answer, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165691/35559)