Follow curve, but keep vertical alignment
I am wanting to model a railing on a footbridge that follows a complex curve; first going to the right, but then descending as it curves, and then descending but straight.
I can get the base object to follow the curve, but when it starts to do down, the verticals of the unit go normal to the curve, rather than staying vertical.
The tilt tool allows them to be adjusted around the axis of the curve, but not around an axis normal to the curve.
I did find this, but the first solution does not work for me; it is described as abusing a bug in Blender four years ago so I guess has been fixed? The second solution will only work for a helix.
I also am aware of "dupliverts" but I want the base object to appear all along the curve, not just as the vertices (I also cannot get them to work for me, but that is another issue).
Just for background, this is the bridge I am trying to model - it is to 3d print.
https://www.networkrailmediacentre.co.uk/news/innovative-first-of-its-kind-railway-footbridge-replaces-one-of-the-uks-most-dangerous-level-crossings

see Gorgious' answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve/165691#165691 or use geometry nodes

Thanks, that was enough to get me going in the right direction.
